# Configuring Route table on Win10 with a VPN and Hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, routing

I am new to routing tables and have no experience modifying the route table prior.

My machine has an ethernet card, wireless adapter and a VPN connection.

Currently, when I am connected to the VPN, all the traffic on my machine is routed through the VPN (as expected), as well as traffic on the hotspot hosted through my wireless adapter.

What I am trying to achieve by configuring the Routing table is to route all my machine's traffic through my internet connection and route all my hosted hotspot's traffic through the VPN.

I haven't had any success in modifying the route table.

Below is what my route table looks like with a hosted Hotspot and a VPN Connection.

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.120   4516
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.21     36
        10.0.0.21  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.21    291
  101.226.197.188  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.120   4261
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.120   4516
    192.168.1.120  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.120   4516
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.120   4516
    192.168.123.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.123.1   4536
    192.168.123.1  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.123.1   4536
  192.168.123.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.123.1   4536
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.120   4516
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.123.1   4536
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.21     36
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1   4556
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.120   4516
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.123.1   4536
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.21    291
===========================================================================
```

192.168.1.120 would be my machine's address.

192.168.123.1 would be my Hosted Hotspot's "gateway"? I have no idea if the term is correct.

101.226.197.188 is the VPN server I am connected to.

Any guidance would be appreciated.